# Какой сервис использовать для отлова краша и ошибок в Android

Tags: java, android

Используя Fabric для дебажинга удаленных телефонов. Если возникают ошибки то я получаю их. На днях столкнулся с не приятной ситуацией. Приложение высылает логи в том случае если приложение запустилось.

Есть ли сервис или библиотека для отлова краша, чтобы она работала после того как краш случится.

Допустим запустил приложение и сразу получил ошибку прямо на старте "Приложение остановленно".

В таком случае FABRIC.IO НЕ РАБОТАЕТ!. И как быть теперь((

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что «[вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Недавно занимался разбором данного вопроса. Советую https://console.firebase.google.com (вообще много чего умеет) и https://www.bugtags.io/ 
В случае второго - в классе унаследованного application в методе onCreate() вы инициализируете и запускаете эту утилиту. Если краш случился до инициализации - то естественно врятле отловит, но можно уже сказать, что скорее всего проблема на стороне пользователя